# How to write JDOQL Query to get data from multiple objects(Relational Objects)

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, jdoql

I want to write a JDOQL  query(JDOQL Delarative or JDOQL Single String ).
Here are my classes

```
public class Customer
{
String Cid;
String Name;
String Email;
String City;
Set<Address> addresses=new HashSet<Address>();
}
public class Address 
{

String Aid;
String City; 
String Location;
}
```

1-N RelaitonShip between Customer and Address objects.

here's my database query

select c.Name,c.Email,a.City,a.Location from user.MASCUSTOMER c inner join user.MASADDRESS a on c.Cid= a.Cid;

How can i represent above query in the form of JDOQL (Delcarative or Single String)?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: select this.Name,this.Email,this.addresses from com.domain.Customer

Comment: and how do you expect that to look ? addresses is a multi valued field so cannot be selected. You can refer to the address easily enough using addresses.contains(address) and then select address.blah

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried like this and i got the data .     SELECT this.Email,this.Name,b1.Location,b1.City,b1.Aid FROM com.join.onetoMany.Customer ; query.declareVariables("com.join.onetoMany.Address b1");

Comment: which is obviously not an INNER JOIN ...

Comment: yes you are absoultely correct. it's cross join.If we set filter as addresses.contains(addObj) then it will become Inner Join.